# How do I create a basic menu bar with selections using webgl/three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

The [documentation for three.js 3-D viewer](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/55/) is hard to follow for beginners. I was wondering what's the basic outline for creating a menu bar or selector with options for a 3-D viewer using three.js / webGL?

Also, how can I make a gradient selector? e.g let's say to change color or opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Look for examples using the dat.gui.min.js which can be found in https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/libs/dat.gui.min.js.

Comment: You do realize there are no whitespaces and/or indentations to make the code readable and understandable?